# Mouse to world position without gluUnProject?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to implement an editor like placing mod with opengl. 
When you click somewhere on the screen an object get placed in that position.

So far this is my code

```
void RayCastMouse(double posx, double posy)
{
    glm::fvec2 NDCCoords = glm::fvec2( (2.0*posx)/ float(SCR_WIDTH)-1.f, ((-2.0*posy) / float(SCR_HEIGHT)+1.f) );
    glm::mat4 viewProjectionInverse = glm::inverse(projection * camera.GetViewMatrix());
    glm::vec4 worldSpacePosition(NDCCoords.x, NDCCoords.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glm::vec4 worldRay = viewProjectionInverse*worldSpacePosition;
    printf("X=%f / y=%f / z=%f\n", worldRay.x, worldRay.y, worldRay.z);
    m_Boxes.emplace_back(worldRay.x, 0, worldRay.z);
}
```

The problem is the object isn't placed at the correct position, worldRay vec3 is used to translate the model matrix.

Can anyone one please help with this i will really appreciate it.
By the way division the worldRay xyz component by worldRay.w is setting the object at the camera position.

Comment: Do you use perspective projection? If so then the [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide) is missing. Note there exists [`glm::unProject()`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00666.html#ga36641e5d60f994e01c3d8f56b10263d2)

Comment: You mean that I should divide worldRay xyz component by its w component?

Comment: I can only see a short snippet of your code, but yes.

Comment: I use perspective projection and doing the division will result in the object being placed right in current camera position 
This is full source code : pastebin.com/9eFECv7b

Comment: what if you put something else in the w component of your ```glm::vec4 worldSpacePosition(NDCCoords.x, NDCCoords.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);``` something close to the z you want in eye space maybe (near + far / 2)

Comment: Changing the z will drastically change the position calculated so its really far away but I noticed that there is only one coordinate which is wrong (apparently its z)